# pointcloud in ros with eclipse

Tags: roscpp, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm ubuntu 12.04 , groovy user.

I'm learning pointcloud in ros and want to use Eclipse(Kepler) for IDE.

When making with catkin, Code is perfect.(didn't show any error)

But Eclipse couldn't index some codes(in pointcloud).

I made package for eclipse by following command.

```
catkin_make --force-cmake \
  -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
  -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j4
```

After doing this, I imported [build] folder in Eclipse.

Many red lines are appeared under code about ros, pcl.

For example, `ros::init(argc, argv, "pcl_test_node")`, `pcl::PointXYZ point` ...etc

I solved this problem with following progress.

1. [Project]-[Properties]-[C/C++ General]-[Preprocessor Include Paths...]-[Providers]
   then, check [CDT GCC Build Output Parser] and
   [CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings[shared]]
2. [Project]-[Properties]-[C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols]
   then, delete include path [/usr/include/eigen3]
3. rebuild.

Finally, I removed many red lines in codes, but not in some parts of pcl.

In the next code, Eclipse couldn't index two parts.

1. cloud->points
   it showed points as '?' and didn't index the members of points.
   and cloud->points.push_back(...)
   error message was 'Method 'push_back' could not be resolved'
2. iterator
   iter->x = 10.0; -> red line under 'x' appear
   And error message was 'Field 'x' could not be resolved'

I think there may be other things I didn't realize yet.

I did many things for correcting this problem but I failed.

Any one who had same problem, please help me.

And thank for your reading in advance.

source code is here

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    ros::init(argc,argv,"pcl_test_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::NodeHandle p_nh("~");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        cloud->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(i*10.0,2.0,3.0));
    }

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::iterator iter;

    iter = cloud->begin();

    for(;iter != cloud->end(); iter++){
        iter->x = 10.0;
    }

    while(ros::ok());
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113096/pointcloud-in-ros-with-eclipse/) by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-27**:
"and I made package for eclipse": how exactly did you do this? If you used catkin to generate the Eclipse project files, and your pkg depends on the PCL integration pkg, I think catkin should add the PCL include dirs automatically for you.

**Comment by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on 2013-12-29**:
Yes, I did it by catkin. Command is following.

catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are doing everything right. Now right click on your project folder, then select Index/Rebuild in the popped-up menu. It will take time to re-index.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0